# ssh login with publickey still ask password

Tags: ssh

I have add public key id_rsa.pub to remote /home/user authorizationkeys. About permission this file was 600 and parent dir .ssh was 700. I have also modified sshd_config.
when I perform `ssh -vv user@remote` errors show below

```
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/hjjj/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/hjjj/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55b3d8c54bc0)
debug2: key: /home/hjjj/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/hjjj/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug3: Wrote 84 bytes for a total of 1309
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list password,publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/hjjj/.ssh/identity
debug3: no such identity: /home/hjjj/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/hjjj/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 388 bytes for a total of 1697
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/hjjj/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/hjjj/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/hjjj/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/hjjj/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
123_hjjj@remote's password: 
debug3: packet_send2: adding 48 (len 65 padlen 15 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 148 bytes for a total of 1845.
```

--- edit ---
Thanks first. I checked below: I haved login client with non-root `userA` and I want to login remote server with non-root `userB` which I can access successfully with password authentication. I also add userA's `id_rsa.pub` to userB's `authorized_keys` file. The `sshd_config` was---

```
# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandRunAs nobody
```

And I can't find auth.log under `/var/log` but `/var/log/secure`. After I execute `ssh userB@remote -p 9998` on client, the log output was:

```
sshd[22208]: Connection closed by 192.168.5.38
```

Comment: The `/var/log/secure` seems a bit sparsely. You could try `journalctl _COMM=sshd -n 50` or `journalctl sshd -n 50`. Do you have any firewall or fail2ban installed?

Answer (score 1):

When you have problems with ssh, it's always a good idea to start ssh with `-v`.
From your log you can see that you offered your key (`Offering public key: /home/hjjj/.ssh/id_rsa`),
but it wasn't accepted (missing `Server accepts key`)

The next steps on the client side should be:

- Verify you are using the correct user
- Verify that you are connecting to the expected server

Then you should switch to the server:

- Check your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` for `PubkeyAuthentication yes`
- Check the entries in `/var/log/auth.log`

Comment: Thanks. Followed your opinion, I checked these issues. I have edit the question body and add the check result. Please go ahead and read the words.